# Conda build fails with `Aborting implicit building of eggs.` message

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, recipe, conda-build

I am trying to build a new conda package based on an old one. The repo and code is available for [Theme Material Darcula](https://github.com/adhadse/theme-material-darcula/). Theme-material-darcula Jupyter labextension builds and install perfectly fine on my system. But the conda build . command fails for me on `Aborting implicit building of eggs. Use pip install. to install from source.`

The traceback is here:

```
 cmdclass = create_cmdclass(
/home/adhadse/anaconda3/conda-bld/theme-material-darcula_1657766513713/work/setup.py:50: DeprecatedWarning: install_npm is deprecated as of 0.8 and will be removed in 1.0. Use `npm_builder` and `wrap_installers`
  install_npm(HERE, build_cmd="build:prod", npm=["jlpm"]),
running install
/home/adhadse/anaconda3/conda-bld/theme-material-darcula_1657766513713/_build_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
/home/adhadse/anaconda3/conda-bld/theme-material-darcula_1657766513713/_build_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
Aborting implicit building of eggs. Use `pip install .`  to install from source.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 488, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 477, in execute
    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 186, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3088, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2211, in build
    utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, rewrite_stdout_env=rewrite_env,
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 411, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adhadse/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 391, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/home/adhadse/anaconda3/conda-bld/theme-material-darcula_1657766513713/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My Conda recipe (`meta.yaml`) is as follows:

```yaml
package:
  name: "theme-material-darcula"
  version: "3.2.0"

source:
  path: .
  git_rev: v3.2.0
  git_url: https://github.com/adhadse/theme-material-darcula

build:
    script: python setup.py install -f

requirements:
  host:
    - python
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - wheel
    - jupyter-packaging
  run:
    - python
    - jupyterlab>=3.0.0

about:
  home: https://github.com/adhadse/theme-material-darcula
  license: BSD
  license_family: BSD
  license_file: LICENSE
  summary: "Darcula theme for JupyterLab with Material Design. Modelled after the classic Intellij theme."

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - adhadse
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

I'm building the package the wrong way. The package is supposed to be built using python `setuptools` via:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

which will create tarball file `dist` directory.

This file is supposed to be published to PyPI. A bash script will make the job a whole lot easier (do make sure to create an account on TestPyPI and PyPI):

```
# Adapted from https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp/blob/master/scripts/publish_pypi.sh

rm dist/*
python3 setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/* -r testpypi
echo "Published to testpypi"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to publish to pypi?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) twine upload dist/*; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

The script will first create tarball file and then first publish it to TestPyPI, if all looks fine, continue with publishing on PyPI.

### Publishing to Conda

The same python package can be published to Conda via `anaconda-client`:

```
conda activate <enironment-name>
conda install anaconda-client
anaconda login
```

Then upload it:

```
anaconda upload dist/*
```